# Using GPS Coordinates and stop locations to determine progress on route

Tags: c#, gps

I am working on a new project in which I receive updates from a serial port.
The data from the serial port is Vehicle, Route, Trip, Driver, LONG_GPS, LAT_GPS
I can read the data and I store it in a database for processing in a second app.

I have a schema which contains various stops with the respective GPS coordinates.

STOP1 - STOP2 - STOP3 - etc... and we have vehicle driving in 2 directions.

I am wondering how its possible to calculate which stop the vehicle is driving to next - only by comparing the GPS coordinates we receive to the database?

Since I have never worked with GPS, and this is the only program I will be needing this I hope someone could help me on my way.

Is there some formula that can be used to calculate this?

Comment: nope, its an old system. I can add timestamps myself. But the vehicle is pinged every 30 seconds, so the last data i receive is the newest. To be complete, there is also an CRC transmitted over the serial port.